Can both conditions be true when each depends on another
I seem to be confused by such two examples. The first example is:
std::atomic<int> x = 1;
//thread 1:
int expected = 1;
if (x.compare_exchange_strong(expected,0,relaxed,relaxed) == true){ // #1
    x.store(2,relaxed);  // #2
}
//thread 2:
int expected = 2;
if (x.compare_exchange_strong(expected,3,relaxed,relaxed)==true){  // #3
}

In this example, it is impossible that #3 reads the value written by #2 but #1 returns false. I prove that in this way: #2 is invoked only when the condition at #1 is true, so it is impossible that #1 returns false while #3 returns true. I don't know whether there is a formal way to prove that's impossible(for example, from the perspective of the formal wording or modification order).
Consider the second example:
std::atomic<int> x = 2;
std::atomic<int> y = 0;
//thread 1:
if(x.exchange(2,Relaxed) == 1) { // #1
  y.store(1,Relaxed); // #2
}
//thread 2:
if(y.exchange(2,Acquire) == 1){ // #3
    x.store(1,Release); // #4
}

However, applying the above logic to this example seems to not work. In the second example, can both conditions be true? Using the above logic, if #1 returns 1, that means #1 reads #4, and #4 is invoked only if #3 reads #2, and #2 is invoked only if #1 returns 1, so the proof seems to form a cycle. However, from the perspective of memory order, since #4 does not synchronize with #1 and #2 does not synchronize with #3, the condition being true does not impose on how the operations to the other variable are reordered. In other words, when #3 reads #2, #1 and #4 is still unordered, as well as #3 and #2 is also unordered when #1 reads #4.
Is there a formal way to work on both examples?
Updated:
The second example is much like the example in [atomics.order] p9
[Note 7: The recommendation similarly disallows r1 == r2 == 42 in the following example, with x and y again initially zero:
// Thread 1:
r1 = x.load(memory_order::relaxed);
if (r1 == 42) y.store(42, memory_order::relaxed);
// Thread 2:
r2 = y.load(memory_order::relaxed);
if (r2 == 42) x.store(42, memory_order::relaxed);
— end note]

[atomics.order] p8 says:

Implementations should ensure that no “out-of-thin-air” values are computed that circularly depend on their own computation.

However, this wording just uses should, which is not mandatory. So, the second example is still possible that both conditions are true?
How about this one?
std::atomic<int> v = {0};
//thread 1:
if(v.load(acquire) == 1){ // #1
   v.store(2,release);  // #2
}
//thread 2:
if(v.load(relaxed) == 2){ // #3
   v.store(1,relaxed);  // #4
}


This doesn't seem like correct code. First argument is T&, so literal is not accepted.

Another strange thing is:  == true (which is obsolete boilerplate), I do not why I can se this so often.

@MarekR sure, but this question only focus on the atomic memory order, so a comprehensive example is brief here.

My understanding is that the "should" in the out-of-thin-air rule is simply because the rule itself is not stated in a precise rigorous way - my guess is that the committee struggled with how to do so.  So they left it as a "should" so that they can't be accused of trying to bind implementers to an ill-defined rule.  But the intent is "you know what we mean by this, please do it".

@NateEldredge: Indeed, I looked into this in an answer to What formally guarantees that non-atomic variables can't see out-of-thin-air values and create a data race like atomic relaxed theoretically can? - I quoted http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0668r5.html as We still do not have an acceptable way to make our informal (since C++14) prohibition of out-of-thin-air results precise.  They would make it a formal requirement if they could figure out how to state it without disallowing things they don't want to forbid.

AFAIK, there are no real-world C++ implementations where out-of-thin-air values can occur, and the intent of the committee is that there shouldn't ever be.

@PeterCordes That is, the out-of-thin-air value is technically permitted. The judge of out-of-thin-air value is in terms of the dependency chain. So, if changing the second example only to use the single atomic object, for example: x is initially 0 //thread 1: if(x.load(relaxed) == 1){x.store(2,relaxed);} // thread 2: if(x.load(relaxed)==2){x.store(1,relaxed)}, can both conditions be true, and if that is, is this called out-of-thin-air value?

Yeah, cross-confirming speculation between threads is one of hypothetical mechanisms.  And yes, formally permitted, so if you want to call that "technically", you can.  This is not something that real programs have to worry about, it's only a problem for formal verification.

@PeterCordes Well, this question is tagged with language-lawyer, so I didn't prepare to discuss it from practice. So, an out-of-thin-air value can still be produced even though these operations are on the same atomic object, as shown in the above code?

@NateEldredge How to interpret the first example, does the first example have the possibility of the out-of-thin-air value? The computation of #3 seems not to depend on its computation. I didn't find a formal way to state that it's impossible that #3 returns true but #1 returns false for the first example.

Oh, I didn't notice your comment had all the ops on the same object, I was in a hurry when I looked at it.  If you want to talk about whether formal verification (ignoring the very important "should" requirements) could prove that such a cycle was allowed or not, ok.  I think it's probably not allowed in that case due to the coherency rules.  If you look at the modification-order and load values necessary for such a cycle to happen, it conflicts with both loads being ordered ahead of their stores (because sequenced-before and same object).

@PeterCordes However, the coherence order is used to form a single total order, and an invalid single total order means that would be impossible. In this case, there are no seq_cst operations(i.e. single total order is irrelevant), the modification order is valid because load operations are not taken into account to the order, as well there is no synchronization in this example impose the load happens-before the corresponding store, IIUC, no formal wording in the current standard prevent the example form the out-of-thin-air value?

@PeterCordes Oh, seems I'm wrong. If the load in t2 reads the store(2), it means store(2) < store(1) in MO(as per [intro.races] p17), as well as if the load in t1 reads the store(1) it means store(1) < store(2) (as per  [intro.races] p17 too), so when two conditions is true, the MO should be store(2)<store(1)<store(2), which is invalid, so it's impossible.

The above comment inspires me how to formally interpret the first example in my original question. If #3 read #2 and #1 return false, it would mean #1 was a pure load and it must read 3 written by #3 otherwise it would be a RMW, since #1 load is sequenced-before #2 and reads #3, so  [intro.races] p17 says #3 < #2, #3 reads #2 means #2 < #3, so if the assumption were true, the MO would be #3 < #2 < #3, which would be an invalid MO, so the assumption cannot be true. Right?

@PeterCordes I find another form of example, I'm not sure whether this is OOTA. For example: x = 0, y = 0; //t1: if(x.load(relaxed)==1){y.store(2,relaxed);} //t2: while(y.load(relaxed)==0){} x.store(1,relaxed); If this is a kind of OOTA, is it necessary to change the store to y be release and the load to y be acquire to prevent from OOTA that is technically possible? Or, because it's only technically possible, can the practice code ignore the possibility?

Looks like OOTA to me; t2 leaving the while loop and making its store visible to t1 is only possible if t1 has already seen its store and done y=2.  Both threads need to have speculatively-executed stores visible to each other and confirm each others' speculation.  So yeah, probably changing either of the load to acquire or either of the stores to release would make this formally impossible.  Real code should of course just use relaxed if that's sufficient for whatever algorithm they're implementing.

And BTW, feel free to post an answer to your question now that you've understood why your single-variable example doesn't allow OOTA, and what's different when there are two.  It takes a lot of mental effort to keep track of which operation number is which and all the details when coming back to a question after a day or so (especially squished into a comment). So I'm usually not interested in writing up a full answer when it's something I've already understood as much as I'm interested in, e.g. in this case when I linked my 2019 answer.

@PeterCordes «Real code should of course just use relaxed if that's sufficient for whatever algorithm they're implementing.» This question arises from my recent reading of the Arc standard library implementation of Rust, which is a practice project, I'm confused about why the store must use release and I got the answer it is used to prevent a similar issue to the example of my last comment.

@xmh0511: Either they're worried about formal verification, or they're concerned over a non-issue.  It can happen that people make mistakes, or worry about things they don't actually need to worry about.  Especially when C++ can't actually provide a formal guarantee that rules this out on intentionally bad/hostile DeathStation 9000 implementations.

@xmh0511 The Rust Arc implementation just follows the logic described in the Boost.Atomic reference counting example. (As opposed to whatever the hell GCC does

@SebastianRedl make_mut is owned by Rust's Arc where shared_ptr doesn't have this method. See details here.

For the first example, if #3 returns true and #1 returns false, #3 would read #2 while #1 must read #3(Otherwise, #1 reads 0, the comparison would be true and the returned value should be true. #1 happens before #2(by sequence-before) and #1 reads #3, as per [intro.races] p17

If a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before an operation B that modifies M, then A takes its value from a side effect X on M, where X precedes B in the modification order of M.

that is, #3 < #2 in the modification order of x. #3 read #2, per [atomics.order] p10

Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value (in the modification order) written before the write associated with the read-modify-write operation.

This implies #2 < #3. If the case is true, the modification order of x should be #2 < #3 < #2, which is an invalid total order, so it's impossible.
For the second example, #3 read #2 requires #2 < #3 in MO of y per [atomics.order] p10, as well #1 reads #4 implies #4 < #1 in MO of x. In each store-load, they do not form the synchronization in terms of the specified memory order, so there is no further requirement on #1 must happen before #4 or #3 must happen before #2, so #1 does not happen before #4 and #3 does not happen before #2, according to [intro.races] p14

The value of an atomic object M, as determined by evaluation B, is the value stored by some unspecified side effect A that modifies M, where B does not happen before A.

Each store is a possible reading value to the corresponding load.
For the last example, if both conditions were true, that would mean #1 read #4 and #3 read #2, again, [intro.races] p17 rules that #4 < #2 and #2 < #4, both true would make the MO for the single x be #4 < #2 < #4, so that's impossible.
